# When querying Facebook Open Graph Api checking for permissions I get a 400 error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I want to check the permissions my users have with:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions&access_token=

but I get the following response:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}

I know the access token works because I can do status updates on behalf of the user and access to his friends info.

This was working fine before. Not sure what's going on

Comment: the url must be: https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=<token>

can't believe i didn't catch it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you already noticed but your URL is missing the {?}

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions&access_token=`

should be

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=`